# Connect localhost Codeigniter app to remote database on Dreamhost

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, localhost, remote-access, dreamhost

I have a number of apps running on Dreamhost and am creating a small app I will use locally to present reports on information stored in various databases. I do not want to host this reporting tool online so I need the app to connect to the remote MySQL server from my machine.

Codeigniter has been giving me an error all afternoon that it can't connect to the remote server, I'm guessing this is down to Dreamhosts security on remote access. I don't have a dedicated IP address so it's not ideal to set on the user account to allow external access. I've tried exploring an IP tracking solution such as No-IP, however I'm not sure if I've configured it properly, or if it'll even the service is capable of allowing my app to access the remote MySQL server when ever it needs.

Does anyone know how to get these working correctly, or am I on the right track??

Comment: Contact support @ Dreamhost.

Comment: I think your plan is shared hosting ? Not possible I think

Comment: Contact your ISP and see if you can get a fixed ip or host name? If your IP is always within a certain range I think you can use wildcards in the dreamhost controlpanel. May be an option.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks- yes I've put a support request in but wanted to know if anyone else already had a working set up and could deliver more explicit detail on config. I will see what DH come back with and whether or not I can use a wildcard on my IP range.